# Image dimensions obtained from bitmapOptions.outWidth and bitmapOptions.outHeight are exchanged

Tags: android, bitmap, height, width, bitmapfactory

I am trying to obtain the dimensions of an image using its URI using the code below. However, for some images (photos taken by phone camera in the portrait mode - an example photo below) the obtained width and height are exchanged (`bitmapOptions.outWidth` *= real height*) and (`bitmapOptions.outHeight` *= real width*).

By real width/real height, I mean the dimensions which can be seen when opening the image in a viewer or when looking at **image details** using file browser of my phone or a PC.

I didn't find a solution for this anywhere here. Could anyone tell me what is a robust method to obtain always the real width and height of an image using its URI, and why this is happening?!

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // do something
    }

    int imageWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
    int imageHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
```

Example photo **[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3qDp5k45POmO_pOLTE1yrKHIslTIS0u/view?usp=sharing)**.

Comment: If you look at the orientation info then does it match? You always have to take it in accounr using bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, how can I obtain orientation info?

Comment: It is a tag from exif info. And also one in jpeg header i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // It will give you the height and width 

  

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                            try {
                                bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), ImageUri));
                                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                                Log.d(TAG,"Height is : "+h+"\n Width is : "+w);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Use older version
                            try {
                                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), ImageUri);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This however will decode the whole Bitmap first, which I want to avoid. I just need the dimensions.

Comment: It will give the same width and height as with inJustDecodeBounds of course.